# How to use comet (disable output buffering in nginx, it works in apache normally but not nginx)?

Tags: php, nginx, comet, output-buffering

I have a comet-driven chat script in my site

My Servers configuration is  NGINX with PHP-FPM ,  I also have apache installed on different port.

When I try to run the chat script on Apache and I do flood the buffer ( my output buffering size is 1 KB) when I flood it with 1024 character, it flushes automatically That's in apache.

But in nginx it doesn't.

My code is very similar to this

```
<?php

// this is to fill the buffer and start output; and it works on apache normally
echo str_repeat(" ",1024); 


while($condition){

  // Some code here...
  $messages = getMessagesFromDatabase();

 if($messages){
  echo "output";   // output works on apache but not nginx
  flush();
  ob_flush();
 }

 usleep(500000); // 0.5 Second

}


?>
```

in my nginx configuration i turned gzip off, proxy_buffering off,

is there a way to avoid buffering in nginx, I searched a lot here in stackoverflow but I couldn't reach to a solution

**and please notice: I don't want to turn off buffering in all of my php configuration I just want this to happen in the chat script**

Comment: `proxy_buffering` is a directive from HTTP proxy module that has nothing to do with fastcgi.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Upgrade your nginx server {} config:

```
fastcgi_keep_conn on; # < solution

proxy_buffering off;
gzip off;
```

Comment: Combined with setting header('Content-Encoding: none;'); at the start of my php file, this worked for me. Thanks.