# Nginx php-fpm 504 gateway error

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi, http-status-code-504

After hours of searching and debugging I give up!

There are thousands of questions and articles about long running PHP processes but non of them solved my issue.

I have a PHP script with the following codes:

```
$cur = 0; 
    // Second, loop for $timeout seconds checking if process is running 
    while( $cur < 31 ) { 
        sleep(1); 
        $cur += 1; 

       echo "\n ---- $cur ------ \n";
    }
```

It is simply intended to run for 31 seconds.

I have a Nginx, PHP configured as fastcgi in debian server.

I set
    max_execution_time = 600

In

```
/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini
```

I even set it in

```
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

Also set

```
request_terminate_timeout = 600
```

in
    /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

I also made these changes in nginx.conf http section

```
client_header_timeout   600;
client_body_timeout     600;
send_timeout           600;

fastcgi_read_timeout    600;
fastcgi_send_timeout    600;
client_max_body_size    600;
fastcgi_buffers         8 128k;
fastcgi_buffer_size     128k;
```

And put the directives inside server section. and these directives inside location section of nginx configuration

```
send_timeout           600;

fastcgi_read_timeout    600;
fastcgi_send_timeout    600;
client_max_body_size    600;
fastcgi_buffers         8 128k;
fastcgi_buffer_size     128k;
```

But I still encounter the Gateway Timeout error in the browser!
(And Yes! I restarted php-fpm and nginx thousands of times)

Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: I think a representative line (if available) from the nginx error_log would be helpfull.

Comment: There comes a day that not having a single error line makes you sad!

Comment: Ouch, that is harsh. Have my sympathies. Perhaps the [debug log](http://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html) can enlighten you? Quite frankly, your config looks pretty ok.

Comment: Oh thank you you're so kind. Well debugging was a great idea. I did not know about debugging option. But unfortunately it prints nothing useful. The only line that is like an error is readv() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) which I think is something normal with nonblocking IO

Comment: Since I am out of ideas: Can you perhaps show us the part of your config where nginx is passing requests over to php-fpm? The stanza with `fastcgi_pass` in it?

Comment: Of course I do, Thank you for spending your precious time to have a look at em. I've already posted them here at https://serverfault.com/questions/868271/nginx-php-fpm-504-gateway-error?noredirect=1#comment1116978_868271

Comment: I'm afraid that wasn't very revealing. My mind is empty at this point and I can advise no more than to scale back those ... generous buffer sizes back to their defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't take my answer as an insult but, did you make sure that your web server is on and did you try accessing another page of the site?

Comment: OH. No problem. It is up and running anyway

Answer (score 0):

After seeing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13645058/3012385), I tend to believe the situation is a s follows: nginx is trying to fill its FastCGI buffer (which is enabled by default) while your script is taking too long to return the first byte, resulting into the timeout. Provided I am correct, there are two things you need to do in order to resolve this:

1. Switch [`fastcgi_buffering`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_buffering) to `off`
2. alter your script so that [`flush()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) and [`ob_flush()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php) are called after each iteration:

   ```
   while( $cur < 31 ) {
       ++$cur;
       echo "\n ---- $cur ------ \n";

       flush();
       ob_flush();
       sleep(1);
   }
   ```

hth

Comment: I've already tested header('X-Accel-Buffering: no'); which I believe does the same but did not fix anything. Besides that, for the other tests that I call a long running shell script with no output it still gives gateway error...

Comment: Indeed [it does](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_ignore_headers). `flush()` didn't help either?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to include the [`proxy_read_timeout` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_read_timeout) in your Nginx configuration file. My own configuration file looks like this:

```
server {
    proxy_read_timeout 300s;
    ...
}
```

You'll note that that is in my server block, however this directive is also valid inside of the http and location blocks as well.

*Edit to add that this is because Nginx *proxies* requests to the PHP-FPM server; the directives you attempted to use are only valid for content that is being served by Nginx itself, and *not* being proxied.

Comment: If at all, that should be [`fastcgi_read_timeout`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_read_timeout). And OP has already set that sufficiently high. The Proxy and FastCGI parts of nginx are very similar, but they do not interoperate.